# how to bind the model attribute value to spring form select items using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I Have a two drop down boxes when i select one drop down box.second drop down has to display the list of values getting from controller using ajax.when i using this logic the second drop down list values are not getting displayed. These are the drop down lists:

```
    Jsp page:

<form:select path="tournId" id="tournId" onchange="test()">
<form:option value="">Select Tournament</form:option>
<form:options items="${tournaments}" itemLabel="tournamentName" itemValue="tournamentId" />
</form:select>
<form:select path="playerId" id="players">
<form:option value="">Select Players</form:option>
<form:options items="${players}"itemLabel="playerDetails.playerName" itemValue="playerDetails.playerId"/>
</form:select>
```

My ajax call :

```
    function test(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact form").load("ajaxTournament", {
    tournId : $('#tournId').val()
    }, function(data) {
    $("#players").html(data);
    });
    });
    }
```

Controller method :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxTournament", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<TournamentPlayers> ajaxTournament(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, @RequestParam("tournId") Long tournId, Model model) {
    if (session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
    List<TournamentPlayers> tPlayerDetails = tournamentPlayerDao.findTournamentPlayersByTournamentId(tournId);
    model.addAttribute("players", tPlayerDetails);
    return tPlayerDetails;
    }
    }
```

could you please give suggestion to resolve this problem. thanks for your valuable information.

Comment: Can you post the final HTML? Do you have an HTML element with id `players`?

Comment: In Jsp page i have used this drop down list. i have to display here only. i have used the players id in this select box.                            <form:select path="playerId" id="players" >
<form:option value="">Select Players</form:option>
<form:options items="${players}"itemLabel="playerDetails.playerName" itemValue="playerDetails.playerId"/>
</form:select>

Comment: You are getting a JSON result not html. You are directly putting the json as html in your select tag. That isn't going to work.